# mysql trigger sometimes doesn't work, but just sometimes

Tags: mysql, triggers

why does mysql trigger sometimes not called?
let's say like 2 occurences on about 100 insert per day
it happens on all 3 tables on 3 different databases that has this trigger
all 3 tables has exactly same structure, just different branches transaction
and all 3 trigger insert into another table on each database. so all 3 database doesn't related at all

```
    delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER cD AFTER INSERT ON clientTransaction
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
END $$

delimiter ;
```

just sometimes but this cause a tremendous trouble for the whole system
the code is kinda long and complex so i don't copy it here
any idea why this happens?

Comment: what is your full trigger code ?

Comment: maybe some unmet conditions you missed or something. Nobody can tell without seeing the full code

Comment: Possible reasons may be the input values which are being processed in trigger causing it to fail. Do you have mysql errors enabled if yes check mysql error logs may give you some idea.

Comment: i also have a procedure that has exactly the same code as this trigger is. it is for re matching everything if this trigger fails, and everytime i call that procedure it is just fixed. so i think it can't be unmet condition